# KDE / Yakuake: Can move windows with mouse. Pointer turns to text tool when hovering over window borders. Min/Max Close buttons not working

Tags: debian, kde, mouse, window-manager

I was installing a lot of packages attempting to get a USB 3.0 HDMI video card working, but at some point during the process, **I lost the ability to grab window borders, or use the minimize, maximize, close buttons. When hovering over the title bar, the mouse goes form a the default pointer to a the text select cursor.**
Clicking links and writing text within my browser still works, but is slow and inconsistent.

**Troubleshooting:**

I tried removing the modules of the new graphics card, and also tried rebooting, neither work.  However upon log-in there's some screen tearing before the mouse pointer comes up.

**Temporary Fixes**

I googled around and found a suggestion that `kwin` might not be installed and sure enough it wasn't.  After installing with `apt install kwin` and then running `kwin`. This fixed things for a few hrs.

I started having the same problem again, this time it coincided with my pushing <kbd>f12</kbd> to launch `yakuake`. Yakuake failed to appear, and I was no longer able to grab title bars or click to close or min/maximize my windows. `pkill yakuake` fixed the problem.

**Strange behavior of <kbd>F12</kbd>**

I relaunched yakuake and after playing around a bit, I noticed that despite the fact that yakuake wasn't appearing, the problem would go away if I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> again.  It's almost as if a ghost window of of Yakuake was appearing. So I ran an `apt purge yakuake` in attempt to fix this.  Yet before I was able to reinstall I noticed the problem regarding pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> persisted on my main display. Rebooting with yakuake did not change this.

What is happening? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**It's a composting issue.**

I came across [this thread](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/425632-mouse-pointer-disappears) of OpenSUSE users experiencing a very similar issue that also seemed to point toward yakuake. However some of my `.xsession-errors` pointed to composting issues. When I googled "KDE F12" [I discovered](https://userbase.kde.org/Desktop_Effects_Performance) the the following sequence will turn on and off composting:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd>

Executing this, solved all issues.