# Firefox '3 bar' menu not opening

Tags: linux-mint, kde, firefox

I'm running Linux Mint KDE and have been having an issue with Firefox lately. When I attempt to open the the Firefox menu (the one on the right with 3 bars), clicking has no effect.

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> opens the more traditional file menus so I am able to access everything that way.  However I would prefer if Firefox functioned as intended.

I searched the Firefox website for people having similar problems, but the answers on how to fix it have varied.  I've tried the following but none of them have worked:

- Starting in safe-mode
- Refreshing Firefox
- Using the default theme (I   already was)
- Disabling hardware acceleration
- Running Firefox from command-line and looking for errors (there were none)
- renaming `~/.mozilla` and reopening firefox
- `apt purge firefox`  and reinstalling

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be related to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453806/kde-yakuake-can-move-windows-with-mouse-pointer-turns-to-text-tool-when-hove) I asked - composting.  To fix withing KDE I needed to turn off composting by pressing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: This seems to not be a general consequence of compositing. I can access ☰ in Firefox with or without compositing on Kubuntu 18.04.